# Custom form template without any region

Tags: 7, theming

I made a custom log in, register and forget password templates, to hide the theme region and wrote a css code.

the issue here when open the page using [colorbox module](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://drupal.org/project/colorbox&ei=RePPUr-yMpKThQee9IGwBw&usg=AFQjCNGMNfBSC0GrXfQUSRg1KAWgZRNxqQ&sig2=1D-H8eiYnrAhKM4LUl41uw&bvm=bv.59026428,d.bGQ) the regions appear for few second before they hide by css code, what i need to disable the theme region in those custom pages.

any advices?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is search your `page.tpl.php` for parts like:

```
print render($page['region_name']);
```

and then wrap them in appropriate `if` construct, not rendering them at all on pages you don't want to see them rendered.

Alternatively, you can create files named page--user.tpl.php, page--user--login.tpl.php and so on. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713257/2389310) for details. Simply copy default page.tpl.php and remove unneeded regions from a copy.